Spring version crashes, plain Java version does not: "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: gRPC message exceeds maximum size" (immudb4j)
Context
I have two versions of the same program. One is wrapped in a Spring Web application (Spring Boot version 3.3.3) and one is a plain Java application. This program makes use of a library called immudb4j (version 1.0.1) which is used to communicate with an ImmuDB instance (version 1.5.0).
Problem
This program consists of a method that repeatedly opens a session with the ImmuDB instance and then immediately closes it again - there used to be more to it, obviously, but I stripped the code down to the minimum that still provokes the problem.
The Spring Web version crashes at ImmuClient::openSession number 19 or sometimes 20 with the following exception:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: gRPC message exceeds maximum size 4194304: 4784128
The plain Java program, however, does not exhibit this behaviour. It seems to be able to run indefinitely.
Why is the Spring version crashing while the plain Java version is fine?
After some further testing, it might be that this issue arises due to some shared dependency of Spring Boot and immudb4j. The crash does not happen when using Spring Boot version 3.3.0, only with the versions 3.3.1, 3.3.2 and 3.3.3.
Code
Plain Java version
public class Application {

    private ImmuClient immuClient = ImmuClient.newBuilder()
            .withServerUrl("localhost")
            .withServerPort(3322)
            .build();

    public void openAndCloseSessionRepeatedly() {
        int iteration = 1;
        try {
            while (true) {
                immuClient.openSession("defaultdb", "immudb", "immudb");
                immuClient.closeSession();
                System.out.println("Iteration: " + iteration++);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Crashed at request " + iteration + " due to:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().openAndCloseSessionRepeatedly();
    }

}

Spring version
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    private ImmuClient immuClient = ImmuClient.newBuilder()
            .withServerUrl("localhost")
            .withServerPort(3322)
            .build();

    @PostMapping
    public void openAndCloseSessionRepeatedly() {
        int iteration = 1;
        try {
            while (true) {
                immuClient.openSession("defaultdb", "immudb", "immudb");
                immuClient.closeSession();
                System.out.println("Iteration: " + iteration++);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Crashed at request " + iteration + " due to:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

Steps to reproduce
An ImmuDB instance is required. I use version 1.5.0 since this is the one that is supposedly supported by immudb4j: https://github.com/codenotary/immudb/releases/tag/v1.5.0. Simply download the executable and run it. There is also a version on Docker Hub, if preferred.
The Maven version of immudb4j seems to use deprecated dependencies (see https://github.com/codenotary/immudb4j/issues/67), so you will have to overwrite those in your POM file like so:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.codenotary</groupId>
    <artifactId>immudb4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>1.55.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
    <version>1.55.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
    <version>1.55.1</version>
</dependency>

The Gradle version seems to use the correct dependencies, although I have not tested that version.

PS: If you have a reason to down vote this question, please at least provide a comment on what that reason is. I already have one down vote here and I have no clue what I have done wrong...
